# different layouts for different screen size

Tags: android

I finished to develop (application part) the app for my project, but now I have problems with the layout. I created the following folders and edited the xml file: 
layout (default) 
layout-large 
layout-normal 
layout-small 
layout-xlarge

On my smartphone (Galaxy S Advance - screen 800x480), the layout is ok, colleague's smartphone (HTC MINI ONE - screen 720x1280) the app haven't got the appropriate layout. In both cases (my smartphone and colleague's smartphone), android loads layout-normal.

What's wrong ???

Thank you

Comment: its better to use [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) with  [weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight)

Answer (score 2):

You can create different layouts for different Screens width instead of just create small and large `dpi` folders, in this method you will just have one `drawable` folder contains all of your resources and multiple `layout` folders, the main one called **layout** and contains the default layouts in order to run the specified layout in case it didn't find it in another layout folder, and the folders hierarchy as described in [android developers page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) will be like :

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

and for example if you want a customized layouts to 340dp screen width you will create `layout-sw340dp` folder inside res folder, So it will be like

```
res/layout-sw340dp/main_activity.xml
```

and the program will automatically assign the layout to the appropriate folder according to the device width.

Answer (score 2):

Please mind screen densities for layouts. Even though you put layout files in appropriate layout containers it does not mean in anyway that Android will respect the folders as densities too play an important role in the way how Android selects the correct `layout.xml` file.

Any device less than 5 inches will fall under `sw320dp` category your solution would be then to create separate folders named `layout-sw320dp-ldpi`, `layout-sw320dp-mdpi`, `layout-sw320dp-hdpi`, `layout-sw320dp-xhdpi` and `layout-sw320dp-xxhdpi` and put the corresponding xml files in them.

Similarly you can approach other screen sizes like `layout-sw600dp` and `layout-sw720dp` etc with above screen densities.

Comment: Best answer so far, thanks bhai you solved my issue, and saved a lot of time from getting wasted as already some is wasted ..! :)

Comment: @arif, if we are building an app for above 3.2 then there is no use of default layout.xml  right ?? i.e layout-ldpi ,layout-mdpi etc..

Answer (score 0):

As you provide layout-large layout-normal layout-small layout-xlarge 4 layout categories. The layout folder(without any qualifier) will be useless. All devices will fall into the other 4 screen buckets.

From your description, I guess you should remove layout-normal folder from your resource.

In addition, normal, large and the other two are just "ranges". If you want more accurate control over screen sizes, you can use [layout-sw](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I removed layout folder and layout-normal folder, but I have same problems.

Comment: try placing your desired layout for HTC MINI ONE in folder  layout-sw720. This should work. And a good guide is http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I have same problems with galaxy s3 and I want find one solution and I don't want create many folders (one for a screen size).

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove loyout folder for Your app Besouse  The layout folder will be useless

Galaxy S Advance - screen 800x480 layout-hdpi

For devices having 720 * 1280 resolution, you can use layout-w720-h1280 folder

Comment: Thanks for reply. My app will run on all android devices, and so I must find one solution. For example, now I try my app on galaxy S3 (screen: 360x640) and I have layout's problem.